# Visual Studio 2012+ symbolic breakpoint ala XCode

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, breakpoints

Is it possible to set symbolic breakpoint in Visual Studio 2012 and above (ala XCode, https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2013/11/UIViewController-viewDidLoad-symbolic-breakpoint.png ) ?

Comment: Not sure how XCode sets breakpoints, but the picture looks pretty mach like Visual Studio "Data Breakpoint".

Answer (score 0):

Just read about [Symbolic Breakpoints in XCode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html).

The equivalent to that is "Function Breakpoint" in Visual Studio.[image]